# How to calculate discount from products table

Tags: laravel

I have products table which contains `mrp` and `price`. I just want to calculate the discount between them.

I am trying something like this,

```
public function getDiscountProducts(Request $request){

    $response1 = Products::get(['mrp']);
    $response2 = Products::get(['price']);

    $percent = $response1 / $response2 * 100;

    if(!empty($percent)){
        return response()->json([
            'message'=>'All categories Products',
            'code'=>200,
            'data'=>$percent,
            'status'=>'success'
        ]);
    }else{
        return response()->json([
            'message'=>"no Products found in the database",
            'status'=>'error'
        ]);
    } 
}
```

But getting the error,

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to number

Please help me out

Comment: get returns a collection, so your response1 and 2 are actually collections of all elements in the database, one with field mrp and the other with field price. You would need to loop through those to get to individual elements and do the calculations

Comment: How can I do that, can you please help me out

Comment: Do you want to include the difference between the values in the two columns in each row? Since the name is `getDiscountProducts` i'm guessing you want to get a list of products with discounts? Is that it?

Comment: yes @user3532758

Comment: I too will post an answer then

Comment: What does `mrp` stand for?

Comment: yes please, post your answer

Comment: mrp contains the Cost Price and price contains the Selling Price

Comment: So your discount calculation is `mrp/price * 100` and it should be `> 0`?

Comment: So what I am asking is, how would you know if the product has a discount applied, because to me that calculation does not look logically correct, I might be wrong

Comment: yes, something like this, i just want to calculate the discount

Comment: If it's a percentage it will never be 0 or less, it will never be empty so you will end up returning all categories, as it is now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220958/discussion-between-user3532758-and-bhawesh-bhakar).

Answer (score 1):

It will be much easier using `DB Query`. Please follow along.

```
DB::table('products')
->select(\DB::raw('100 - (ROUND((price  * 100) / mrp, 1)) AS discount'))
->get();
```

Comment: This is simlar to what I was going to suggest, but I did/do not understand the calculation

Comment: @user3532758 yes you are absolutely right. I have updated the answer. It should be (selling_price * 100)/mrp

Comment: mrp is my cost price and price is my selling price. I just want to calculate the %, that by how much %, mrp is greater than price

Comment: Formula will be (mrp - price) / mrp * 100

Comment: I have tried (ROUND(((mrp - price) * 100) / mrp, 2)) AS discount

Comment: @BhaweshBhakar cool, you can change the formula as per your requirement. Please accept if the answer helped you.